# How to open .SLN from Release folder

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, sln-file

I have started a new job. And the guy before did not leave me the solutions of the projects he was working on. I can only access the projects- published files from IIS. Is the any way i can open in visual studio the projects with those files, and create solutions for them.
I should mention the project are in as.net MVC5 C#

Comment: Feel free to create yours, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/creating-solutions-and-projects?view=vs-2019#create-empty-solutions

Comment: **If** they're _compiled_ (aka "published") you won't have access to source code. Otherwise see above comment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.